# How to make the numbering of subsections independent from the numbering of sections?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I am writing a constitution for a society.  I would like to have the subsections numbered independently of the way that the sections are numbered, i.e:

```
Section 1
    Subsection 1
    Subsection 2
Section 2
    Subsection 3
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
```

Besides the numbering itself, in contrast to the `remreset` package, `chngcntr` can redefine `\thesubsection` for you to not include the section number within the subsection number.

### UPDATE

Since 2018, `\counterwithout` has been in the LaTeX kernel, so loading the `chngcntr` package is no longer necessary.

Comment: After almost exactly 10 years `:-)` maybe you could edit to reflect the fact that `\counterwithout` has been part of the kernel since a couple of years.

Answer (score 7):

although the numbering of sub/sections depends on the document class you're using, there is a little package called `remreset` that contains the command that will undo the "numbering within".

Comment: An example would be `\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother`. You might need to change `\thesubsection` to not the section number, e.g. using `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}`.