# Start subsection numbering from 2.5 rather than 2.1 in class `article`

Tags: sectioning, numbering, article

In an `article` document, I have sections 1 and 2. the subsections of section 1 go from 1.1 to 1.4, and I want the subsections of section 2 to go from 2.5 onwards (rather than starting at the usual 2.1).

Is there a command to do this automatically, rather than forcing it manually?

Moreover, I am not planning on putting a table of contents, so I would be happy with tricking LaTeX into hiding the first four subsections.

[P.S. Please tell me if the question can be rephrased better, I couldn't find a similar question online]

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15152/82917: the proposed solution is still valid but does not require the `chngcntr` package any more (the corresponding macros have integrated into the kernel).

Comment: Sorry @campa , but that does not seem to answer my question - `\counterwithout` simply removes the section-dependent part of the numbering. But I want to keep it and just 'miss' a few subsections